# Solarized and Terminal in OS X 10.8.4 Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to install the Solarized color scheme for my terminal on 10.8.4 Mountain Lion. I downloaded the .terminal files from https://github.com/tomislav/osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized and followed the instructions in the README which said:

> OS X 10.7 Lion: Double click to install or import into Terminal.app preferences.
>   OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion: Import into Terminal.app preferences.

I declared the terminal as xterm-256color:
[image: Settings]

But the Terminal looks like this:
[image: Terminal]

What can I do so that the all the colors in the Solarized theme show up? You can see in my second screenshot that I ran ls and the directories aren't colored properly.

Comment: I'll clean up some text. What exactly isn't correct about these pictures? Please edit in exactly what you want to see differently or why the settings you have shown us are incorrect.

Comment: The pictures weren't showing up, so I edited it to fix that.

Comment: What is your prompt? and are you expecting ls output to be in colour?

Comment: Mark, yes, I was expecting ls to color directories and executables in different colors similar to how Linux OSes do it.

Answer (score 1):

The bright green, yellow, blue, and cyan foreground colors seem to be almost the same as the default foreground color:

[image]

Or if you were expecting the themes to add colors to new places, they don't. They are Terminal settings files just change some of the settings that can also be changed from Terminal's preferences. You can make `ls` use colors with something like `export CLICOLOR= LSCOLORS=dxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad`.

Comment: I expected it to use the full range of colors shown, some for text color for certain commands. What is the point of the theme if it comes with all those colors and only uses two? Also, where exactly do I put export CLICOLOR= LSCOLORS=dxfxcxdxbxegedabagacad?

Comment: It does use all hues for the non-bright colors, but you could try unchecking "Use bright colors for bold text" or copying the non-bright colors over the bright colors. If you use bash, put the export command in `~/.bashrc` and add `. ~/.bashrc` to `~/.bash_profile`. See [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99688/how-to-persistently-define-aliases-in-terminal/99730#99730).

Comment: Thank you! This did it for me. Out of curiosity, why does adding the export to ~/.bash_profile not work, if, as the other post says, Terminal reads ~/.bash_profile on startup? I tried this, and it didn't work, so I put the export in ~/.bashrc like the other post explained. Also I like having my Terminal text be bold, so I did [this](http://imgur.com/CqGfq1w) in my settings, but the text in the Terminal is still not bold. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Adding the export command to `~/.bash_profile` should work by default, but I don't know why it wouldn't. Your default font seems to be Monaco, which doesn't have a bold typeface.

Comment: Okay thanks! One last thing, I promise. The text colors look "off" in the terminal. For example, when in [MacVim](http://imgur.com/iN3YuTC) vs [Terminal Vim](http://imgur.com/f14Zrk5). Why are the colors washed out/lighter in the terminal than they should be?

Comment: I think it's because the values of the colors are specified as sRGB, and Terminal doesn't convert them to your display's profile. See [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29487).

Comment: Hm, thanks for the info, but it didn't seem to work. Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep to comment on that specific question. I may have to just ask a new question and hope more people see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did have a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28964151/solarized-theme-in-os-x-terminal-having-brighter-font-colors-compared-to-vim), and washed-out colors got fixed by switching to a different [Solarized port](https://github.com/tamul/solarized-osx-terminal-colors). Now everything looks great, completely identical to MacVim.