# Problem persistently defining aliases in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, script, alias

I am trying to persistently define some aliases for my everyday terminal use. I started off with this tutorial: [How to persistently define aliases in Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99688/how-to-persistently-define-aliases-in-terminal), more precisely with Mike's comment.

As he suggested I created a `.bashrc` file and symlinked `.bash_profile` and `.profile` to it.

My two aliases I created in `.bashrc` are the following:

`alias showFiles= ‘defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE; killall Finder’
 alias hideFiles= ‘defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE; killall Finder’`

Now I have a problem, when i open a new bash window in Terminal, i get this error message:

```
-bash: alias: ‘defaults: not found
-bash: alias: write: not found
-bash: alias: com.apple.finder: not found
-bash: alias: AppleShowAllFiles: not found
-bash: alias: TRUE: not found
No matching processes belonging to you were found
-bash: alias: ‘defaults: not found
-bash: alias: write: not found
-bash: alias: com.apple.finder: not found
-bash: alias: AppleShowAllFiles: not found
-bash: alias: FALSE: not found
No matching processes belonging to you were found
```

Could someone please explain why I get this error and/or how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alias command requires you to have no spaces around the = and also you should use " or ' to enclose the string not the curly quote ‘ you have. That quote often appears in pdfs and books when the editing program tries to make things look nice.

so the command should be

```
alias showFiles="defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE; killall Finder"
alias hideFiles="defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE; killall Finder"
```

I can't find a reference for these but they are just things I have learnt :(

Comment: @CedricRBR's single quotes should be double quotes, as Mark indicates, but they should not be 'curly' quotes, either.

Comment: @IconDaemon single quotes ' work as well here

Comment: Agreed, but the examples in the original post are curly, and may be the cause of the problem if present in the .bashrc file, which expects plain text.

Comment: `'`, `"` are valid in these alias definitions.
`´` is invalid, in the sense it is not a metacharacter but a basic one. `bash` will read `´defaults` as a word, the name of a potential command and this "command" is not found. Which it tells to tell the truth :).

Comment: reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-alias