# How to set proxy on OS X Terminal permanently?

Tags: macos, command-line, proxy

For every new session in OS X terminal, I have to make my proxy settings again.  I do this by entering the command

```
export http_proxy="username:password@ip address:port number"
```

Is there a way to make these proxy settings once for all?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your http proxy (just for some web sites not https ones and not for the rest of the internet) can be set for each terminal session by adding the line

```
export http_proxy="username:password@ip address:port number"
```

to your ~/.bash_profile file if using bash (the default from Panther to Mojave) or for later macOS the default shell is zsh and the file to use is ~/.zshrc

Note this will only affect command line programs.

Comment: More recently, zsh is the default shell. In that case, add the command to `~/.zshrc` file.

Comment: Also set `https_proxy` alongside of `http_proxy` because some apps uses https.

Comment: Is there a way to access the password safely without saving it in plain text?

Answer (score 16):

#### Set system-wide HTTP proxy

To globally set an http proxy system-wide on MacOS (not just for a terminal session) you can use:

```bash
networksetup -setwebproxy wi-fi localhost 8080
networksetup -setwebproxystate wi-fi on
```

> This assumes your network interface is called `wi-fi` (or `Wi-Fi`), and that your proxy is running on `localhost` on port `8080`.

To disable the proxy:

```bash
networksetup -setwebproxystate wi-fi off
```

This is equivalent to setting the proxy via mac system settings > Network > wi-fi > Advanced > Proxies > Web proxy.

#### Set system-wide SOCKS5 proxy

```bash
networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxy wi-fi localhost 1080
networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate wi-fi on
```

To disable the socks proxy use:

```bash
networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate wi-fi off
```

#### Getting the correct network interface name

All the commands above assume your netowork interface is `wi-fi`. If you are connected via ethernet then most likely the interface will be `en<SOME_NUMBER>` e.g. `en0` and you'll need to use that instead of `wi-fi`.

To find the active network interface run this from your terminal:

```bash
scutil --nwi | awk -F': ' '/Network interfaces/ {print $2;exit;}'
```

> <sup>If you need a GUI wrapper for setting the HTTP/SOCKS/PAC proxies then check out [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1297771/65975). The [bitbar script](https://github.com/matryer/xbar-plugins/blob/master/System/macos-proxy-switcher.1m.sh) linked in the answer also contains the commands for setting a SOCK5 or PAC proxy. *Update*: ***Bitbar*** has been renamed to [**xbar**](https://github.com/matryer/xbar) — it's an open-source GUI for text-mode scripts written in bash/applescript/node/golang/etc.</sup>

Comment: Not works for me (Catalina v10.15.7)

Comment: Does not work for me in terminal. `curl` works both with and without proxy. Using Big Sur 11.6

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you mean aliases, not proxys.

Add it to ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile. See [this guide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99688/how-to-persistently-define-aliases-in-terminal) for more depth. I don't believe OS X supports a ~/.bash_aliases file.

Comment: No bash directly supports ~/.bash_aliases you call it from ~/.bashrc (which you probably should call from ~..bash_profile as well)

Comment: @Mark Fair, but (to my limited knowledge) some systems do so automagically which makes it easy.