# How do I configure proxy for my terminal with v2ray?

Tags: terminal, proxy

With v2ray on macOX 10.13.6, I can access some sites from Chrome but I cannot access those sites from terminal.

the configuration for v2ray looks like this

```
{
    "v": "2",
    "ps": "\u8bxx-Azure",
    "add": "xx.acrossgw.info",
    "port": 8088,
    "id": "xxx-b6xxx8954c",
    "aid": "16",
    "net": "ws",
    "type": "none",
    "host": "xx.acrossgw.info",
    "path": "\/data",
    "tls": "tls"
}
```

Per this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/227300/359161), this command sets proxy for terminal session

```
export http_proxy="username:password@ip address:port number"
```

I put this line at the end of my ~/.bash_profile

```
export http_proxy="xxx-b6xxx8954c:\u8bxx-Azure@xx.acrossgw.info:8088"
```

but I cannot access those sites from terminal either, how do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a quick stab from the documentation:

It does not appear that v2ray will pick up from the environment the `http_proxy` env var, it needs to be configured via a JSON (or protobuf) file. There's an [example client config file here](https://www.v2ray.com/en/welcome/start.html).

You'd save that file somewhere, then run it in your terminal like this:

`v2ray --config=/etc/v2ray/config.json` (or wherever your config file lives).

Answer (score 4):

Click the V2ray icon >  Copy HTTP Proxy Shell Export Line
You can get the below command. Run the command in the terminal. You can enable the proxy.

`export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1087;export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1087;export ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080`

[image]

Test with the command in the terminal.

`curl cip.cc`

[image]

Remove the proxy with the command.

`alias unproxy='unset all_proxy'`

Test again with the command in the terminal. Your ip location is change.

`curl cip.cc`

[image]

The better solution is to set the below `alias` command in your zsh or bash.

```
alias proxy='export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1087;export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1087;export ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080'

alias unproxy='unset all_proxy'
```

Then you can use the command `proxy` to enable the proxy. Use the command 'unproxy' to disable the proxy.